WinUI3 assign width control stars programmatically
I'm trying to assign programmatically the width of several TextBox in a StackPanel with the stars units. Somthing like this xaml:
<StackPanel Orientation=Horizontal>
    <TextBox Name=Text1 Width="2*">
    <TextBox Name=Text1 Width="*">
    <TextBox Name=Text1 Width="*">
</StackPanel>


But programmatically I can't achieve it because the TextBox.Width() only accept double values.
I have tried with text.Width(GridLengthHelper::FromValueAndType(2, GridUnitType::Star)); but no luck.
I'm thinking to do it my self calculating from the width of the StackPanel, but these width can change in my app when the user resize the window an I would need to recalculate...
How can I avhieve it, programmatically?

Or you can calculate them in the FrameworkElement.SizeChanged Event.

You need to use Grid instead of StackPanel:
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBox
        Grid.Column="0"
        Text="Hello" />
    <TextBox
        Grid.Column="1"
        Text="World" />
    <TextBox
        Grid.Column="2"
        Text="!" />
</Grid>

or
<Grid ColumnDefinitions="2*,*,*">
    <TextBox
        Grid.Column="0"
        Text="Hello" />
    <TextBox
        Grid.Column="1"
        Text="World" />
    <TextBox
        Grid.Column="2"
        Text="!" />
    </Grid>

If you want to do this programmatically, take a look at the code below . It's in C# but should be the same logic for C++.
<Grid Loaded="TextBoxesGrid_Loaded" />

private void TextBoxesGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is not Grid grid)
    {
        return;
    }

    grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(
        new ColumnDefinition
        {
            Width = new GridLength(2, GridUnitType.Star)
        });
    grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(
        new ColumnDefinition
        {
            Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star)
        });
    grid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(
        new ColumnDefinition
        {
            Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star)
        });

    grid.Children.Add(
        new TextBox
        {
            Text = "Hello",
        });

    grid.Children.Add(
        new TextBox
        {
            Text = "World",
        });

    grid.Children.Add(
        new TextBox
        {
            Text = "!",
        });

    for (int i = 0; i < grid.Children.Count; i++)
    {
        TextBox gridTextBox = grid.Children.ElementAt(i) as TextBox;
        int columnIndex = i;
        Grid.SetColumn(gridTextBox, columnIndex);
    }
}


Yes, but I need to do it programmatically, no XAML, because my app have an UI dinamic. No way to assign stars sizes programmatically?

Updated my answer but it's in C#. Hope it helps.

Thank you Andrew, I'm trying the same logic en C++, but it won't work... In C++ when I assign the Width property, only can pass a double. I try something like: textBox1().Width(GridLengthHelper::FromValueAndType(2.0, GridUnitType::Star)); but not compile... maybe I need to do it another way.

You need to set the Grid's ColumnDefinitions not the TextBox's Width.
